# JMS serializer how to handle serialization manually?

Tags: symfony, jms, jmsserializerbundle

I want to desirialize JSON manually with JMSSerializerBundle. I got some troubles with HandlerCallback. Here is a code:

```
namespace Company\Bundle\Model;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\HandlerCallback;
use JMS\Serializer\JsonDeserializationVisitor;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\TypeParser;
use JMS\Serializer\Serializer;

class Blog
{
    protected $blogName;

    protected $blogUrl;

    protected $blogCategory;
    /**
     * @Type("array<Company\Bundle\Model\Post>")
     * @SerializedName("data")
     */
    protected $posts;

    /**
     * @param mixed $posts
     */
    public function setPosts($posts)
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    /**
     * @HandlerCallback("json",  direction = "deserialization")
     */
    public function deserializeFromJson(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, array $data, DeserializationContext $context)
    {
        $this->blogName = $data['data'][0]['blogName'];
        $this->blogUrl =  $data['data'][0]['blogUrl'];
        $this->blogCategory = $data['data'][0]['blogCategory'];

        $this->posts = ????;
    }
}
```

What should i add instead of ???? to get array of object Company\Bundle\Model\Post

Comment: The only official examples / documentation are here: https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/tests/JMS/Serializer/Tests/Fixtures/Article.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somthing like this:

```
/**
 * @HandlerCallback("json",  direction = "deserialization")
 */
public function deserializeFromJson(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, array $data, DeserializationContext $context)
{
    $this->blogName = $data['data'][0]['blogName'];
    $this->blogUrl =  $data['data'][0]['blogUrl'];
    $this->blogCategory = $data['data'][0]['blogCategory'];

    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    for ( $data['data'][0]['posts'] as $post_data ){
        $this->posts->add(new Post($post_data));
        // OR
        $this->posts->add(Post::deserializeFromJson($post_data));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but this will create new empty object $this->addPost(new Post($post_data)); This $this->addPost(Post::deserializeFromJson($post_data)); is not right because there is no such static method.

Comment: Indeed, you need to write your own `Post::deserializeFromJson` method :)

Comment: In this case what is a benefit to use JMS/serializer if i should write own deserializeFromJson method :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually re-use your other objects, and local annotations.

```
/**
 * @HandlerCallback("json",  direction = "deserialization")
 */
public function deserializeFromJson(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, array $data, DeserializationContext $context)
{
    $typeParser = new TypeParser();

    /** @var ClassMetadata $metadata */
    $metadata = $context->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataForClass(self::class);
    $visitor->startVisitingObject($metadata, $this, $typeParser->parse(self::class), $context);

    $visitor->visitProperty($metadata->propertyMetadata['blogName'], $data['data'][0], $context);
    $visitor->visitProperty($metadata->propertyMetadata['blogUrl'], $data['data'][0], $context);
    $visitor->visitProperty($metadata->propertyMetadata['blogCategory'], $data['data'][0], $context);
    $visitor->visitProperty($metadata->propertyMetadata['posts'], $data['data'][0], $context);
}
```